# Why unable to make a single radio select highlighted once selected from a form group

Tags: html, angular, radio-button, label, form-control

To make a radio select from a form group, I provided the option list using ngFor directive. All was fine. As I don't actually need a full list of those options at certain conditions, I had to make each option as an input individually. Unfortunately, checking on one option highlighted the others although the value is indeed what I selected.

I referred many successfully answers to the similar issue here, but none works for my case. Anyone please refer to below code and screenshot to find out a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

1. using ngFor (works fine!)

```html
<div class="row ml-5" formGroupName="deliveryForm">
            <div class="col-6 form-group" *ngFor="let method of deliveryTypes">
                <input type="radio"
                    id={{method.id}}
                    (click)="setShippingPrice(method)"
                    value={{method.id}}
                    formControlName="deliveryType"
                    class="custom-control-input">
                <label for="{{method.id}}" class="custom-control-label">
                    <strong>{{method.name}} - {{method.price}}</strong>
                    <br>
                    <span class="label-description">{{method.description}}</span>
                </label>
            </div>   
        </div>
```

2. input individually (individual condition for each input not added yet)

```html
<div *ngIf="deliveryTypes" class="row ml-5" formGroupName="deliveryForm">
            <div class="col-6 form-group">
                <input 
                    type="radio"
                    id="{{deliveryTypes[0].id}}"
                    (click)="setShippingPrice(deliveryTypes[0])"
                    value="{{deliveryTypes[0].id}}"
                    name="deliveryType"
                    class="custom-control-input">
                <label for="{{deliveryTypes[0].id}}" class="custom-control-label">
                    <strong>{{deliveryTypes[0].name}} - {{deliveryTypes[0].price}}</strong><br>
                    <span class="label-description">{{deliveryTypes[0].description}}</span>
                </label>

                <input 
                    type="radio"
                    id="{{deliveryTypes[1].id}}"
                    (click)="setShippingPrice(deliveryTypes[1])"
                    value="{{deliveryTypes[1].id}}"
                    name="deliveryType"
                    class="custom-control-input">
                <label for="{{deliveryTypes[1].id}}" class="custom-control-label">
                    <strong>{{deliveryTypes[1].name}} - {{deliveryTypes[1].price}}</strong><br>
                    <span class="label-description">{{deliveryTypes[1].description}}</span>
                </label>

                <input 
                    type="radio"
                    id="{{deliveryTypes[2].id}}"
                    (click)="setShippingPrice(deliveryTypes[2])"
                    value="{{deliveryTypes[2].id}}"
                    name="deliveryType"
                    class="custom-control-input">
                <label for="{{deliveryTypes[2].id}}" class="custom-control-label">
                    <strong>{{deliveryTypes[2].name}} - {{deliveryTypes[2].price}}</strong><br>
                    <span class="label-description">{{deliveryTypes[2].description}}</span>
                </label>
               </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "highlighted" by running your snippet. Have you tried replacing the <strong> tags with <div>?

Comment: thanks for your time looking at my issue. I tried replace strong tag with div, no help. "highlighted" here means that only the checked on radio stands out with colored other than multiple. That is the single select for radio, I meant.

Comment: your forget  the `formControlName="deliveryType"`

Comment: good catch. issue remains after change 'name' to 'formControlName'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple place each input and label in a div. The issue is gone.